# Preauthenticate and forward username to default authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security, so forgive me if this is straight forward.

We are in the process of rewriting the UI layer of a legacy web app. We decided that the new UI layer would be based on Spring MVC with Spring Security to handle security and authorization.

I've been looking at setting up security in the new app to mimic what we had in the previous app. In the old app, we basically have two entry points for users:

- Internal users are authenticated via HTTP basic authentication which
  performs the actual authentication using the clients LDAP server.
  This authentication mechanism is configured on a JBoss server, so is
  container-managed.
- External users logs in via a third-party authentication service that validates the credentials. External user roles are stored in the LDAP server. When the third-party authentication service authenticates the credentials, a username and hardcoded password is used to authenticate them on the JBoss configured security domain so their roles are loaded.

I figured I would try and mimic this functionality in Spring Security but have so far come up short. I use an in-memory authentication provider in place of LDAP in my tests since its easier. I've got http basic authentication working for internal users.

I've tried subclassing `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and supplying the credentials through this, but it does seem to forward the credentials properly to the "default" authentication provider.

```
<http>
    ...
    <http-basic />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ExternalLoginFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="ExternalLoginFilter" class="com.foo.ExternalLoginPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="internal-user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_INTERNAL" />
            <user name="external-user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_EXTERNAL" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>`
```

Here is my ExternalLoginPreAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class ExternalLoginPreAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest req) {
    return "password";
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest req) {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if(session != null){
        return session.getAttribute("app.external-user.username");
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

I also tried setting up a "preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" like some examples propose, but that seems to expect that my `ExternalLoginPreAuthenticationFilter` has resolved user roles as well.

Any ideas how I can configure Spring MVC to allow the scenario above? Basically, I need to be able to tell Spring Security to perform the login against the default authentication provider with a specific username/password in the least intrusive way, preferably without too many hacks (which the old application uses).

**Note on solution:** While Ralph's solution seem to work, specifically this portion:

> I think using the PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider and set the preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService variable to your in memory AuthenticationUserDetailsService should be the way to go.

However, it also seems to play badly with CSRF protection. When I log in, and is redirected to the homepage, any HTTP POST from this page will fail the CSRF check. A subsequent GET of the homepage before POST'ing fixes the issue, so it seems Spring somehow overwrites the current CSRF token improperly. I found a [bug report](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2376) detailing the problem. Even though it claims to be fixed, I have not been able to work around it. While the bug report links to a workaround in the forum, I have instead used to following workaround, which seems to work.

The trick is to inject the `AuthenticationManager` into your `Controller` and do the login yourself:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/external-login")
public class ExternalLoginController {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public ExternalLoginController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    // ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(){
        // Do this after third-party authentication service accepts credentials
        String username = "external-user"; // or whatever username was authenticated by third-party
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken credentials = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, "password");
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(credentials);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever set a breakpoint in AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doAuthenticate to check if this method is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the `AuthenticationProvider` is selected in the `AuthenticationManager` by the  authentication credential class that is provided (often a subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationToken`).

Your `PreAuthenticationProcessingFilter` will create a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`, that is normaly "consumed" by an `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`.

So either:

- you register a `AuthenticationProvider` that "consume" the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` token, and do what you want, or
- you change the `PreAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to create an other kind of token (for example a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` that is "consumed" by the "normal" authentication provider you use (subclass of `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`))

I think using the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` and set the `preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService` variable to your in memory `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` should be the way to go.

Comment: I tried your last advice, and it seems to work (using a UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper as the UserDetailsService). However, when I log in using this method, CSRF protecting seems to break down. Subsequent form posts gives me a http 403 with CSRF failure error message? I tried injecting the AuthenticationManager into the Controller handling external logins, and if I call that directly and subsequently set returned Authentication on the SecurityContextHolder, then CSRF and login works as expected. Any ideas?